# Refresh DataTables after save data from modal component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTables for listing student with an "Add New" button. On clicking the "Add New", a modal opens from another `component.ts` file.

When record is saved, it show in the DataTable list, but no DataTable operation is working like search by new entered record or pagination updated or filtering.

Overall We need to refresh table so it updates the data in the DataTable. I am not familiar with how `modal.component.ts` refresh table from `student.compnent.ts` file.

Student.component.ts

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {StudentService} from "../../services/student.service";
import {CompanyService} from "../../services/company.service";
import {Student} from "../../models/student";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;
@Component({
selector: 'my-students',
templateUrl: './students.component.html'
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {
students: Student[];
selectedStudent: Student;
sources: any;
error: any;
constructor(private router: Router, private studentService: StudentService, private companyService: CompanyService) {
}
getStudents() {
this.studentService.getStudents().then(students => {
this.students = students
$(function () {
var oTable =  $('#example2').DataTable({
"bPaginate" : $('#example2 tbody tr').length>3,
"iDisplayLength": 3,
"bAutoWidth": false,
"bInfo" : true
});
$('#advance_search').keyup(function(){
oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
});
});
});
}
ngOnInit() {
this.companyService.getCompany().then(companyData => { 
if(companyData) {
this.sources = companyData.sources;
}
});
this.getStudents();
}
studentChanged(event) {
var changedItem = event;
var findChangedItem = this.students.find( item => {
return item._id == changedItem._id;
});
if(findChangedItem) {
console.log('TODO: update students data in list.');
} else {
this.students.push(changedItem);
}
}
sourcesUpdated(event) {
this.sources = event;
}
detailsStudent(_id) {
this.router.navigate(['/app/studentdetails', _id]);
}
}
```

addstudent.component.ts(modal component)

```
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {Component, Input,Output, EventEmitter,  OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';
import { IMyDateModel, IMyDpOptions } from 'mydatepicker';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import {Address} from "../models/address";
import {Student} from "../models/student";
import {Company} from "../models/company";
import {StudentService} from "../services/student.service";
import {CompanyService} from "../services/company.service";
import { ValidationService } from '../services/validation.service';
declare var moment: any;
@Component({
selector: 'popup-addstudent',
templateUrl: './addstudent.component.html'    
})
export class AddStudentsComponent implements OnInit {
student: Student;
// sources: Sources[];
error: any;
navigated = false; // true if navigated here
studentForm: any;
sources: any;
studentAddress: Address;
//companyData: Company;
@ViewChild('studentCloseBtn') studentCloseBtn: ElementRef;
@Input()
set sourceList(sourceList: any) {
this.sources = sourceList;
}
@Output()
loadChanges: EventEmitter
<any>
= new EventEmitter
<any>
();
visaExpiresOn: any;
visaExpiresOnFormatted: any = null;
public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
};
constructor(private studentService: StudentService,   private companyService: CompanyService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
private route: ActivatedRoute, private validationService: ValidationService, private notificationsService: NotificationsService) {
this.student = new Student();
this.validationService= validationService; 
this.reload();
}
ngOnInit() {
}
//convert from :date:{year: 2017, month: 9, day: 13} 
onDateChanged(event: IMyDateModel) {
//set the date to yymmdd format for saving
this.visaExpiresOnFormatted = moment(event.formatted, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log("date changed");
console.log(this.visaExpiresOnFormatted);
}
save() {
if (this.studentForm.valid) {
this.student.visaExpiresOn = this.visaExpiresOnFormatted;
console.log("in save");
console.log(this.student);
this.studentService
.save(this.student)
.then(student => {
this.loadChanges.emit(student);
this.student = student; // saved student, w/ id if new
this.notificationsService.success(
'Saved',
'Student saved successfully.',
{
timeOut: 5000,
showProgressBar: true,
pauseOnHover: false,
clickToClose: false,
maxLength: 110
}
);
this.student = new Student();
this.closeModal();
})
.catch(error => {
this.error = error;
console.log(error);
// Show alert error message.
this.notificationsService.error(
'Not Saved',
'Some error occured.',
{
timeOut: 5000,
showProgressBar: true,
pauseOnHover: false,
clickToClose: false,
maxLength: 50
}
);
});
}
else{
// Show alert message.
this.error = "Please enter required fields!";
this.validationService.validateAllFormFields(this.studentForm);
}
}
reload() {
this.error = null;
this.studentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
'firstName': ['', Validators.required],
'lastName': ['', Validators.required],
'middleName': [''],
'address1': [''], 
'address2': [''],
'city': ['', []],
'state': ['', []],
'country': ['', []],
'postcode': ['', []],
'phone': [''], 
'source':[''],
'visaExpiresOn': [''],
'isVisa': [''],
'email': ['', [Validators.required]]
});
this.student = new Student();
this.studentAddress =  this.student.address;
}
closeModal(): void {
this.studentCloseBtn.nativeElement.click();
}
//allowd only number
keyPress(event: any) {
const pattern =  /^[0-9._-]+$/ ;
let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
//console.log("dot...."+event.keyCode);
if(([8, 9, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46,110,190].indexOf(event.keyCode) == -1 ) && !pattern.test(inputChar)) {
if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
event.preventDefault();
}
}
}
}
```

addstudent.component.html

```
    <div  class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <form [formGroup]="studentForm" (submit)="save()">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" #studentCloseBtn >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Add Student</h3>
        </div>
        <div  *ngIf="student"  class="box box-body modal-body" style="padding:25px 10px">
            <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger text-center">{{ error }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-offset-right-1" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <input formControlName="firstName" id="firstName" title="First Name" placeholder="FIRST NAME *" type="text" class="form-control adstu_btn" [(ngModel)]="student.firstName" /> 
                        <control-messages [control]="studentForm.controls.firstName"></control-messages>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <input formControlName="middleName" type="text" title="Middle Name" [(ngModel)]="student.middleName" class="form-control adstu_btn" placeholder="MIDDLE NAME"  autocomplete="off"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <input  formControlName="lastName" type="text" title="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="student.lastName" class="form-control adstu_btn" placeholder="LAST NAME *"  autocomplete="off" required />
                        <control-messages [control]="studentForm.controls.lastName"></control-messages>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input  formControlName="phone" type="text" title="Telephone" [(ngModel)]="student.phone" class="form-control adstu_btn" placeholder="TEL"   autocomplete="off"  (keypress)="keyPress($event)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input  formControlName="email" type="text" title="Email" [(ngModel)]="student.email" class="form-control adstu_btn" placeholder="EMAIL *"  autocomplete="off" required />
                        <control-messages [control]="studentForm.controls.email"></control-messages>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                        <select  formControlName="source" title="Source" class="form-control round" [(ngModel)]="student.source" >
                        <option *ngFor="let sourceval of sources" [ngValue] = "sourceval._id" >{{sourceval.sourceName}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 button-bottom" style="margin-top:7px !important" >
                        <a href="#" class="plusbtn1" title="Add Source" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSource"><span>+</span></a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <my-date-picker formControlName="visaExpiresOn" title="Student Visa Expiry Date" name="visaExpiresOn" [(ngModel)]="visaExpiresOn" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" placeholder="VISA EXPIRES ON" 
                            (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)" >
                            </my-date-picker>
                            <control-messages [control]="studentForm.controls.visaExpiresOn"></control-messages>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12" >
                        <div style="margin-top: 12px;" class="form-group">
                            <input  formControlName="isVisa" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="student.isVisa" >
                            <label class="" id="Label_padding">No Student Visa</label>
                            <control-messages [control]="studentForm.controls.isVisa"></control-messages>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  >Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-default1" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share your code? Otherwise, we can't see where you're getting stuck.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Sorry for late ! Question with Updated Code. Please check again

Comment: Can anybody help me out in this issue....